# Invalid syntax on export PDF

Tags: arcpy, syntaxerror

I'm getting an invalid syntax error on line 20. Anybody see what's wrong?

```
import arcpy
import os

geo1 = GetParameterAsText(0)
goe2 = GetParameterAsText(1)
saveLoc = GetParameterAsText(2)
exportLoc = GetParameterAsText(3)

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('CURRENT')
mxd.findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths(geo1, geo2)

df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "BLOCK", df):
    if lyr.name == "BLOCK":
        df.extent = lyr.getSelectedExtent()
df.scale = 10000

arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
mxd.saveACopy(os.path.join(saveLoc, (mxd.title + ".pdf"))
arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, (os.path.join(exportLoc, (mxd.title + ".pdf"))))

del mxd
```

The error I get is:

```
Executing: ReplaceWorkspacePathandExport \\Client\L$\17TSLB002_Morice\A95421_1_NO_82\Submission_GDB\A95421_1_TBA_Digital_Sub_July24_2017.gdb \\Client\L$\17TSLB001_Bulkley\A71932_1\Submission_GDB\A71932_1_TBA_Digital_Sub_Dec13_2017.gdb \\Client\L$\17TSLB001_Bulkley\A71932_1\Submission_PDFs \\Client\L$\17TSLB001_Bulkley\A71932_1\Submission_PDFs
Start Time: Thu Dec 14 11:07:15 2017
Running script ReplaceWorkspacePathandExport...
Failed script ReplaceWorkspacePathandExport...
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (ReplaceWorkspacePaths_and_Export2.py, line 20)
Failed to execute (ReplaceWorkspacePathandExport).
Failed at Thu Dec 14 11:07:15 2017 (Elapsed Time: 0.48 seconds)
```

Comment: Please include the error message, also what is the value of mxd and exportLoc variables?

Comment: I updated the question with the rest of the script and the error.

Comment: Your workspace paths have a $ character, not sure if that is causing issues.  Maybe try it first on a simpler local paths (e.g. C:/Temp/first.gdb, and C:/Temp/second.gdb).

Comment: Wouldn't it give the error on line 19 at the mxd.saveACopy if that was the case? I'm working and executing this script in a remote desktop server and it names the paths to any drive on my local computer with the $ symbol instead of a colon symbol.

Comment: findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths() statement comes before saveACopy() statement so it is not reaching the saveACopy() statement

Comment: Why is it saying the errors from line 20? I had named the script itself ReplaceWorkplacePathAndExport, so the error message is a little confusing.

Comment: Likely not the cause of your issue, but line 20 has a bunch of extra parenthesis and could be simplified to arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, os.path.join(exportLoc, mxd.title + ".pdf"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your parentheses is open.

Change:

```
mxd.saveACopy(os.path.join(saveLoc, (mxd.title + ".pdf"))
```

to:

```
mxd.saveACopy(os.path.join(saveLoc, mxd.title + ".pdf"))
```